# How to replace multiple key-value pairs in a dictionary in python?

Tags: python

I have a dictionary with multiple key value pairs resembling this:

```
sampling_strategy = {1259: 302, 568: 245, 698: 132, 534: 126, 971: 112, 446: 103, 614: 102, 860: 97, 989: 96, 1037: 89, 1309: 82, 1251: 76, 1339: 76, 556: 74, 1245: 68, 502: 67, 1429: 61, 985: 58, 1212: 58, 953: 52, 13: 51, 1256: 49, 1002: 47, 979: 45, 185: 43, 961: 43, 841: 41, 1697: 41, 510: 37, 994: 37, 1421: 37, 747: 36, 1218: 36, 1451: 36, 1201: 35, 1248: 35, 1449: 34, 982: 33, 1435: 33, 579: 32, 1342: 32, 1425: 31, 487: 29, 1044: 29, 583: 28, 682: 28, 1031: 28, 1200: 28, 207: 27, 236: 27, 891: 27, 964: 27, 1185: 27, 1221: 27, 1283: 26, 1234: 25, 1452: 25, 1555: 25, 582: 24, 1715: 24, 225: 23, 1027: 23, 1464: 23, 999: 22, 1237: 22, 1595: 22, 27: 21, 211: 21, 754: 21, 969: 21, 1568: 21, 193: 20, 787: 20, 959: 20, 1196: 20, 581: 19, 216: 18, 505: 18, 752: 18, 956: 18, 1282: 18, 1392: 18, 70: 17, 621: 17, 966: 17, 1560: 17, 40: 16, 51: 16, 1413: 16, 1773: 16, 60: 15, 83: 15, 627: 15, 1444: 15, 1631: 15, 1703: 15, 1716: 15, 110: 14, 214: 14, 626: 14, 894: 14, 1022: 14, 1552: 14, 1646: 14, 624: 13, 1396: 13, 1450: 13, 1642: 13, 1684: 13, 495: 12, 965: 12, 1034: 12, 1397: 12, 1448: 12, 1553: 12, 94: 11, 117: 11, 218: 11, 753: 11, 1238: 11, 1554: 11, 1593: 11, 1774: 11, 98: 10, 191: 10, 790: 10, 1336: 10, 1378: 10, 1491: 10, 1627: 10, 1644: 10, 250: 10, 492: 10, 530: 10, 1020: 10, 1047: 10, 1130: 10, 1406: 10, 1457: 10, 1693: 10, 1696: 10, 107: 10, 194: 10, 657: 10, 842: 10, 892: 10, 1260: 10, 1479: 10, 1682: 10, 1686: 8, 1771: 8, 4: 7, 23: 7, 501: 7, 655: 7, 788: 7, 893: 7, 908: 7, 1029: 7, 1108: 7, 1147: 7, 1307: 7, 1355: 7, 1363: 7, 1456: 7, 1465: 7, 1666: 7, 1669: 7, 1685: 7, 1690: 7, 124: 6, 201: 6, 683: 6, 1016: 6, 1058: 6, 1113: 6, 1117: 6, 1124: 6, 1135: 6, 1140: 6, 1270: 6, 1271: 6, 1471: 6, 1578: 6, 1639: 6, 1647: 6, 1659: 6, 0: 5, 168: 5, 246: 5, 319: 5, 433: 5, 447: 5, 676: 5, 1033: 5, 1070: 5, 1112: 5, 1167: 5, 1213: 5, 1268: 5, 1286: 5, 1315: 5, 1369: 5, 1394: 5, 1461: 5, 1463: 5, 1531: 5, 1594: 5, 1623: 5, 1628: 5, 1635: 5, 1663: 5, 1689: 5, 1695: 5, 1751: 5, 183: 4, 208: 4, 357: 4, 672: 4, 691: 4, 694: 4, 700: 4, 806: 4, 853: 4, 912: 4, 929: 4, 974: 4, 1023: 4, 1028: 4, 1050: 4, 1084: 4, 1136: 4, 1157: 4, 1215: 4, 1269: 4, 1279: 4, 1324: 4, 1403: 4, 1475: 4, 1529: 4, 1532: 4, 1564: 4, 1566: 4, 1589: 4, 1603: 4, 1615: 4, 1617: 4, 1626: 4, 1630: 4, 1632: 4, 1668: 4, 1679: 4, 1687: 4, 1692: 4, 1694: 4, 1720: 4, 1: 3, 8: 3, 14: 3, 33: 3, 45: 3, 192: 3, 197: 3, 205: 3, 215: 3, 321: 3, 340: 3, 354: 3, 367: 3, 409: 3, 451: 3, 667: 3, 674: 3, 677: 3, 699: 3, 708: 3, 771: 3, 789: 3, 807: 3, 830: 3, 897: 3, 970: 3, 990: 3, 1008: 3, 1074: 3, 1105: 3, 1109: 3, 1131: 3, 1141: 3, 1144: 3, 1151: 3, 1235: 3, 1263: 3, 1281: 3, 1298: 3, 1313: 3, 1337: 3, 1347: 3, 1385: 3, 1411: 3, 1414: 3, 1417: 3, 1420: 3, 1454: 3, 1455: 3, 1563: 3, 1579: 3, 1588: 3, 1638: 3, 1652: 3, 1662: 3, 1671: 3, 1680: 3, 1691: 3, 1699: 3, 1702: 3, 1710: 3, 1714: 3, 1742: 3, 1746: 3, 1772: 3, 1775: 3, 10: 2, 15: 2, 32: 2, 39: 2, 41: 2, 46: 2, 47: 2, 48: 2, 64: 2, 65: 2, 67: 2, 81: 2, 114: 2, 115: 2, 118: 2, 120: 2, 125: 2, 126: 2, 139: 2, 154: 2, 158: 2, 164: 2, 169: 2, 173: 2, 182: 2, 186: 2, 190: 2, 196: 2, 202: 2, 219: 2, 223: 2, 240: 2, 243: 2, 244: 2, 249: 2, 253: 2, 266: 2, 268: 2, 291: 2, 294: 2, 297: 2, 304: 2, 310: 2, 311: 2, 314: 2, 315: 2, 316: 2, 320: 2, 322: 2, 329: 2, 349: 2, 350: 2, 351: 2, 355: 2, 356: 2, 364: 2, 366: 2, 372: 2, 374: 2, 375: 2, 377: 2, 381: 2, 383: 2, 426: 2, 429: 2, 431: 2, 444: 2, 449: 2, 450: 2, 452: 2, 462: 2, 464: 2, 488: 2, 490: 2, 493: 2, 507: 2, 546: 2, 549: 2, 575: 2, 597: 2, 602: 2, 610: 2, 620: 2, 663: 2, 670: 2, 679: 2, 681: 2, 693: 2, 703: 2, 707: 2, 712: 2, 725: 2, 732: 2, 759: 2, 792: 2, 797: 2, 799: 2, 804: 2, 813: 2, 832: 2, 838: 2, 840: 2, 857: 2, 858: 2, 865: 2, 867: 2, 875: 2, 919: 2, 923: 2, 927: 2, 932: 2, 939: 2, 950: 2, 954: 2, 960: 2, 962: 2, 977: 2, 983: 2, 991: 2, 1004: 2, 1009: 2, 1030: 2, 1049: 2, 1052: 2, 1072: 2, 1081: 2, 1087: 2, 1090: 2, 1094: 2, 1106: 2, 1110: 2, 1121: 2, 1126: 2, 1139: 2, 1146: 2, 1152: 2, 1155: 2, 1158: 2, 1163: 2, 1166: 2, 1172: 2, 1177: 2, 1187: 2, 1197: 2, 1199: 2, 1243: 2, 1253: 2, 1258: 2, 1265: 2, 1266: 2, 1273: 2, 1276: 2, 1284: 2, 1288: 2, 1290: 2, 1293: 2, 1302: 2, 1304: 2, 1321: 2, 1357: 2, 1362: 2, 1372: 2, 1380: 2, 1381: 60, 1382: 60, 1384: 60, 1399: 60, 1410: 60, 1412: 60, 1469: 60, 1470: 60, 1472: 60, 1478: 60, 1494: 60, 1506: 60, 1509: 60, 1520: 60, 1547: 60, 1556: 60, 1558: 60, 1580: 60, 1581: 60, 1586: 60, 1592: 60, 1604: 60, 1606: 60, 1611: 60, 1613: 60, 1614: 60, 1622: 60, 1625: 60, 1640: 60, 1654: 60, 1665: 60, 1704: 60, 1731: 60, 1738: 60, 1743: 60, 1749: 60, 1767: 60, 2: 50, 3: 50, 5: 50, 6: 50, 7: 50, 9: 50, 12: 50, 17: 50, 18: 50, 19: 50, 20: 50, 25: 50, 26: 50, 29: 50, 30: 1, 31: 1, 34: 1, 36: 1, 37: 1, 38: 1, 42: 1, 43: 1, 44: 1, 50: 1, 52: 1, 53: 1, 55: 1, 56: 1, 57: 1, 58: 1, 59: 1, 61: 1, 62: 1, 63: 1, 66: 1, 68: 1, 71: 1, 72: 1, 75: 1, 76: 1, 77: 1, 78: 1, 79: 1, 80: 1, 82: 1, 84: 1, 87: 1, 88: 1, 89: 1, 90: 1, 91: 1, 93: 1, 95: 1, 96: 1, 97: 1, 99: 1, 100: 1, 101: 1, 102: 1, 103: 1, 104: 1, 105: 1, 106: 1, 108: 1, 109: 1, 111: 1, 113: 1, 122: 1, 123: 1, 128: 1, 129: 1, 130: 1, 131: 1, 133: 1, 135: 1, 136: 1, 138: 1, 140: 1, 143: 1, 144: 1, 145: 1, 146: 1, 147: 1, 148: 1, 150: 1, 151: 1, 152: 1, 153: 1, 156: 1, 159: 1, 160: 1, 163: 1, 166: 1, 167: 1, 170: 1, 171: 1, 172: 1, 174: 1, 175: 1, 177: 1, 178: 1, 179: 1, 180: 1, 181: 1, 184: 1, 187: 1, 188: 1, 189: 1, 195: 1, 198: 1, 199: 1, 200: 1, 204: 1, 206: 1, 210: 1, 212: 1, 213: 1, 217: 1, 220: 1, 221: 1, 222: 1, 226: 1, 227: 1, 229: 1, 230: 1, 231: 1, 233: 1, 235: 1, 237: 1, 238: 1, 239: 1, 241: 1, 242: 1, 245: 1, 248: 1, 251: 1, 252: 1, 254: 1, 255: 1, 256: 1, 258: 1, 259: 1, 260: 1, 261: 1, 263: 1, 265: 1, 269: 1, 270: 1, 271: 1, 273: 1, 275: 1, 276: 1, 277: 1, 278: 1, 279: 1, 280: 1, 281: 1, 282: 1, 283: 1, 285: 1, 286: 1, 287: 1, 288: 1, 289: 1, 292: 1, 296: 1, 299: 1, 300: 1, 301: 1, 302: 1, 303: 1, 305: 1, 306: 1, 307: 1, 308: 1, 309: 1, 312: 1, 313: 1, 318: 1, 323: 1, 324: 1, 325: 1, 326: 1, 327: 1, 328: 1, 330: 1, 331: 1, 332: 1, 333: 1, 334: 1, 335: 1, 336: 1, 337: 1, 338: 1, 339: 1, 341: 1, 342: 1, 345: 1, 347: 1, 353: 1, 358: 1, 361: 1, 362: 1, 363: 1, 365: 1, 368: 1, 369: 1, 373: 1, 376: 1, 379: 1, 380: 1, 382: 1, 385: 1, 388: 1, 390: 1, 395: 1, 396: 1, 397: 1, 399: 1, 400: 1, 401: 1, 402: 1, 403: 1, 404: 1, 405: 1, 406: 1, 407: 1, 408: 1, 412: 1, 413: 1, 414: 1, 415: 1, 416: 1, 418: 1, 420: 1, 421: 1, 423: 1, 425: 1, 427: 1, 428: 1, 430: 1, 432: 1, 436: 1, 437: 1, 438: 1, 440: 1, 441: 1, 442: 1, 445: 1, 454: 1, 455: 1, 456: 1, 457: 1, 458: 1, 459: 1, 460: 1, 461: 1, 463: 1, 466: 1, 467: 1, 468: 1, 469: 1, 470: 1, 471: 1, 472: 1, 474: 1, 475: 1, 476: 1, 477: 1, 478: 1, 479: 1, 480: 1, 481: 1, 482: 1, 483: 1, 485: 1, 486: 1, 489: 1, 494: 1, 496: 1, 497: 1, 499: 1, 500: 1, 503: 1, 504: 1, 506: 1, 508: 1, 509: 1, 512: 1, 513: 1, 514: 1, 516: 1, 517: 1, 519: 1, 520: 1, 522: 1, 523: 1, 524: 1, 525: 1, 527: 1, 529: 1, 531: 1, 532: 1, 535: 1, 536: 1, 537: 1, 539: 1, 540: 1, 541: 1, 542: 1, 543: 1, 544: 1, 545: 1, 547: 1, 550: 1, 551: 1, 552: 1, 553: 1, 554: 1, 557: 1, 558: 1, 559: 1, 560: 1, 561: 1, 563: 1, 564: 1, 566: 1, 567: 1, 569: 1, 570: 1, 571: 1, 572: 1, 576: 1}`
```

I want to replace all the pairs where the value is 1 to 50 and all where the value is 2 to 60 and so on:
My resulting dict should look like {572:50, 576:50} for the last two values. Is there a way to do this without having to manually change each value? I want to change all values when value<= 10 to a higher value.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: what happens to `{1259: 302}` ?

Comment: @ParitoshSingh: that remains as it is.. so I only want to change the values of keys which have value <= 10;

Comment: What do you mean by "and so on"? would 3 be 70 and 4 be 80?

Comment: @liamhawkins: sorry for the wrong wording ... so I want to replace all values where values <=10; .. so when value = 1, I want to make it 50, 2 should be 60, 3 should be 70...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done by looping through the dictionary with `.items()`

```
for key, value in sampling_strategy.items():
     if value <= 10:
         sampling_strategy[key] = 40 + value * 10
```

Comment: Use "for key, value in sampling_strategy.iteritems()" for python 2.7

Comment: `.items()` works in 2.7 unless you need an iterator specifically

Answer (score 1):

How to do it with a dictionary comprehension:

```
new_dict = {key: value * 10 + 40 if value <= 10 else key: value for (key, value) in sampling_strategy.items()}
```